# matplotlib second timeseries not plotting

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot two timeseries in the same plot, but the second plot is not shown properly. Sorry, I can't upload plots due to some limits.

Given two timeseries,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': [pd.Timestamp('2022-04-20 12:00:00'), 
                  pd.Timestamp('2022-04-20 13:00:00'), 
                  pd.Timestamp('2022-04-20 14:00:00')], 
    'value': [0, 1, 2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': [pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 12:00:01'), 
                  pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 13:00:01'),
                  pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 14:00:01')], 
    'value': [0, 1, 2]})
```

If I plot `df1` before `df2`, only `df1` shows in the plot,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', figsize=(10, 5), ax=ax, label='df1')
df2.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', color='orange', ax=ax, label='df2')
```

Even if I specify `xlim`, `df2` is not plotted,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xlim=(pd.Timestamp('2022-04-20 11:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 15:00:00'))
df1.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', figsize=(10, 5), xlim=xlim, ax=ax, label='df1')
df2.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', color='orange', ax=ax, label='df2')
```

But if `df2` is plotted before `df1`, everything works,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', color='orange', ax=ax, label='df2')
df1.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', figsize=(10, 5), ax=ax, label='df1')
```

I've figured out that it is caused by different schemas of timestamps. `df1` is at X o'clock, but `df2` is at X o'clock and 1 second. When I modified `df2` to X o'clock, it works,

```
df2_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': [pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 12:00:00'), 
                  pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 13:00:00'),
                  pd.Timestamp('2022-04-21 14:00:00')], 
    'value': [0, 1, 2]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', figsize=(10, 5), ax=ax, label='df1')
df2_new.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', color='orange', ax=ax, label='df2_new')
```

How can I plot two timeseries properly without modifying data or manually adjusting their order? These timeseries are passed from outside with no limitation.

---

Edit:

In the first case (i.e. plot `df1` before `df2`), if I apply `plt.autoscale()`, `df2` is plotted at 1970s, while `df1` is plotted at 2022.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', figsize=(10, 5), ax=ax, label='df1')
df2.plot(x='timestamp', y='value', color='orange', ax=ax, label='df2')
plt.autoscale()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think df.plot() overwrites the previous plot.

```
for Timestamp in df1.Timestamp:
    plt.plot(df1.Timestamp,df1.value)
    
for Timestamp in df1.Timestamp:
    plt.plot(df2.Timestamp,df2.value)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).